# Blank subreport using iReport 5

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Why my subreport it isn't shown? Look, the JRXML code is very simple.
When I press the view button in iReport only the main report is shown.
The two subreports aren't shown.
Any help is welcome.

report1_subreport1.jrxml:contains only a static text in the title band

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1_subreport1"language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="05f9b4fc-35fa-4335-8fd3-a02a78526a7c">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="b9a3b1af-3d85-4902-a374-0674a0ea5c9f" x="0" y="7" width="218" height="72"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Mensage1]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

report1.jrxml : contains a static text and two subreports, the same defined early.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryNewPage="true" uuid="cb5ca789-5eeb-4fce-914b-626d1da98104">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/home/david/teste/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString language="XPath">
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<title>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
        <subreport>
            <reportElement uuid="b762ee33-6259-4103-92c0-f0dda0139a2f" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="61"/>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "report1_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</title>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="af42ea5b-3b1e-4701-8077-6bd72597c929" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="61"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Main Message"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
        <subreport runToBottom="false">
            <reportElement uuid="b762ee33-6259-4103-92c0-f0dda0139a2f" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="61"/>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "report1_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Do your subreports run independently? What happens if you change the subreport file extension to .jrxml in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the problem.

The fields "When no data" were set to "no pages" and should be "All Section, No Detail".
Another reason is the second subreport is in deatail band thus won't be printed.
I didn't test in runtime, only in iReport however i think it will run.

Comment: but after i did also i dont get any sub reports displayed, you have any idea in it